# Efficient code to avoid circular references in c# object model

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

I have an excel like grid where values can be typed referencing other rows

To check for circular references when a new value is entered, i traverse the tree and create a list of values referenced thus far, if the current value is found in this list, i return an error thus avoiding a circular reference. This is infrequent enough where extreme performance is not an issue but...

Question - is there a better way ? I'm told it's not the most optimal but no answer was provided so on to the experts @ SO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this help [What would be a good algorithm for a circular reference check in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428267/what-would-be-a-good-algorithm-for-a-circular-reference-check-in-this-case) ?

Comment: hmmm, it might if only i can find my reference books :)         thanks, will take a look, might take a while though !